# Check multiple customer group id numbers

Tags: php, if-statement, range

I am new to PHP & have the below code:

```
{if $checkcustomer->id_default_group==8 || 9 } {hook h="agProduct"} {/if}
```

I need to make the groups more than just two, we have 5 groups that we want to show the hook agProduct to them, I don't think it would be like this:

```
 {if $checkcustomer->id_default_group==8 || 9 || 10 || 11 || 12 } {hook h="agProduct"} {/if}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you must write out the data on both sides of the operand.  The closest that you can get to what you tried is to use `in_array()` with an array of valid values.

You can write out each condition like this:

```
{if ($checkcustomer->id_default_group==8 ||
     $checkcustomer->id_default_group==9 ||
     $checkcustomer->id_default_group==10 ||
     $checkcustomer->id_default_group==11 ||
     $checkcustomer->id_default_group==12) } {hook h="agProduct"} {/if}
```

or you can write upper and lower bounds using `>` and `<` like this:

```
{if ($checkcustomer->id_default_group>7 && $checkcustomer->id_default_group<13) } {hook h="agProduct"} {/if}
```

> or most succinctly you can write `in_array()` once, like this:
>
> ```
> {if in_array($checkcustomer->id_default_group,[8,9,10,11,12]) } {hook h="agProduct"} {/if}
> ```

As a bonus, `in_array()` also makes code modification simple.  If you want to include id group `5`, you can just add it to the array.  With the other methods, you must write an additional condition.

Comment: First method worked great, thank you "very" Much, that was helpful

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if (($checkcustomer->id_default_group > 7) && ($checkcustomer->id_default_group < 13))
```